# IE8 radio buttons .change() event fires even without change

Tags: jquery, html, radio-button

It seems that the following HTML and jQuery event do not work as expected in Internet Explorer. In IE the event is fired every time the radio button is clicked (even if it is the currently selected one). In Chrome it works fine. Any ideas for an IE fix?

```
<input id="system-open" type="radio" name="system-closure" value="false" checked="">Open
<input id="system-close" type="radio" name="system-closure" value="true">Close
```

```js
$("input[name=system-closure]:radio").change(function () {
    alert($(this).val());
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store the previous value in a data attribute on a containing element to see if the selection has actually changed. Try this:

```
<div class="radio-container">
    <input id="system-open" type="radio" name="system-closure" value="false" checked="">Open
    <input id="system-close" type="radio" name="system-closure" value="true">Close
</div>
```

```js
$("input[name=system-closure]:radio").change(function () {
    var $radio = $(this);
    var $container = $radio.closest('.radio-container');
    var currentValue = $radio.val();
    var oldValue = $container.data('old-value');

    if (currentValue != oldValue) {
        // the selection has been changed, do something...
        alert($(this).val());
    }

    $container.data('old-value', currentValue);
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it worked. However had to tweak it a little bit as the first time you click on the same active radio button it still fired. I am also using .val() instead of data as I am not familiar with it (yet).

`var oldValue = $("input[name=system-closure]:radio").val();
 $("input[name=system-closure]:radio").change(function () {
    var currentValue = $(this).val();
    
    if (currentValue != oldValue) {
        // the selection has been changed, do something...
        alert('There was a change in selection!');
    }
    oldValue = currentValue;
 });`

Comment: I don't understand what you've posted

Comment: tried to use backticks to post code in my previous comment but did not work. Basically I tweaked the code so that it gets the old value before the change event is bound to it, otherwise it still fires. I have also replaced .data with .val as I am more familiar with that. Thanks for the solution :)